# How to force a LongListMultiSelector to use a custom class for its items?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, silverlight-toolkit

My custom class for the items looks like:

```
public class CustomLongListMultiSelectorItem : LongListMultiSelectorItem
{
    public CustomLongListMultiSelectorItem()
        : base()
    {
    }

     // other implementations...
}
```

Where can I allocate this item-class to the LongListMultiSelector?

Comment: What would be the purpose of overriding the LongListMultiSelectorItem class?